# Value is the expected value, but if statement won't recognize?

Tags: python

```
monsters.create()

for monster in World.monsters:
    if monster.name == "Valley Wolf":
        Game.Log("Found the wolf!")
    else:
        Game.Log("Could not find the wolf!")
```

The above code results in "Could not find the wolf!" printing, but when I change it to the following:

```
monsters.create()

for monster in World.monsters:
    Game.Log(monster.name)
```

it prints "Valley Wolf".....I'm very confused why the value seems to be "Valley Wolf", and yet the if statement is returning False and running the else....

Comment: There might be extra characters in `monster.name` different from what you are comparing to

Comment: Could be whitespace? try `monster.name.strip()  == "Valley Wolf"`

Comment: Can you show the names?

Comment: LPython, that was it. Thank you. I'll have to figure out why my function was storing whitespace as part of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of extra characters, so try:

```
for monster in World.monsters:
    if "Valley Wolf" in monster.name:
        Game.Log("Found the wolf!")
    else:
        Game.Log("Could not find the wolf!")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be     `if  "Valley Wolf" in monster.name:`